# ConfuserEx obfuscation and adding .dll as reference to VS project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I want to obfuscate a single .dll file (to hide constants). When I confuse .dll compiled as release for any processor AND application is started from .exe - everything works fine.

Unfortunately this .dll is meant to be a "key" for some things in our database that we want to give to someone else to use. But I don't want them to be able to recover this source code in like 2-3 clicks by DotPeek or any other reverse engineering tool for C#. They are still testing their things, so they start their app from Visual Studio.

When I add non-obfuscated .dll to my test project as reference - everything is fine. But when I add already obfuscated .dll as reference I get 'FatalExecutionEngineError'. And that's unfortunately the whole point - I want them to have this .dll for usage and testing purposes, but after obfuscation it may not be possible for them to use it from Visual Studio.

Am I doing something wrong or should I just use a different obfuscation tool?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/issues/580

Comment: Visual Studio needs to do some reflection in order to allow you to consume an API, so you can't just encrypt everything and expect to be able to work with it.